# Pie chart - How to get the percent text at the right location?

Tags: r, ggplot2, pie-chart

I have issues having the percentage information at the right locations on my pie chart. Could someone very kindly help me on that? Thank you very much!

```
        #sample dataframe       
        d <- data.frame(facet=c('a','b','c', "d"), value=c('0.46','0.11','0.18', "0.25"))
        d$value <- as.numeric(as.character(d$value))


blank_theme <- theme_minimal()+
  theme(
    axis.title.x = element_blank(),
    axis.title.y = element_blank(),
    panel.border = element_blank(),
    panel.grid=element_blank(),
    axis.ticks = element_blank(),
    plot.title=element_text(size=14, face="bold")
  )

        d$perc <- round(d$value/sum(d$value) * 100,0)
        d$pos <-  cumsum(d$perc) - sapply(d$perc,function(x) cumsum(x)-0.5*x)

        bp <- ggplot(data=d, aes(x="", y=perc, fill=facet))+
          geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity") + 
          geom_text(aes(x="", y=pos, label=paste0(perc,"%"))) +
          #geom_text(aes(x="", y=value/4+ c(0, cumsum(value)[-length(value)]), label=percent(value/100))) 
          scale_fill_manual(values = c("a" = "#b2df8a", "b" = "#238b45", "c" = "#636363", "d"="orange"))
        bp

        pie <- bp +  coord_polar("y", start=0) + blank_theme +
          theme(axis.text.x=element_blank())  
        pie
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens that for some reason `ggplot2` goes to the other direction when dealing with labels. Hence, instead using

```
d$pos <-  100 - (cumsum(d$perc) - sapply(d$perc, function(x) cumsum(x) - 0.5 * x))
```

gives

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is straightforward to achieve with `ggpiestats` function. It only requires slight modification to your dataframe-

```r
library(ggstatsplot)
set.seed(123)

# data
d <-
  data.frame(
    facet = c('a', 'b', 'c', "d"),
    value = c(46, 11, 18, 25)
  )

# plot with statistical details in the subtitle
ggstatsplot::ggpiestats(data = d,
                        main = facet,
                        counts = value)
```

[image]

In case you don't want statistical test details and want to further customize aesthetics of the plot, you can also use `ggplot2` functions-

```r
# customizing it further
# change the slice label
ggstatsplot::ggpiestats(data = d,
                        main = facet,
                        counts = value,
                        slice.label = "both",
                        package = "wesanderson",
                        palette = "Royal2") +
  ggplot2::labs(subtitle = NULL)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-02-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed ggpiestats suggestion!